# An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file .mdf

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I've been surfing here and there for an answer and i can't find anything that works for me. Can someone help me with this?

I'm trying to do an app that has to work with db and when i try to connect them, i got this. I'm working with SQL Server 2017 and Visual Studio 2017.

[image]

I've been reading that its the dir that's not "supported" (UNC i think?) so i tried to move the DB to other dir and if i do that, i get this error

[image]

This is the connection string

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Program 
Files\Microsoft SQL 
Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\CineX.mdf;Integrated 
Security=True;Connect Timeout=30
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you do not distinguish between `localdb` and `SQL Server Express`.

In OP you are connecting to `localdb`, in your answer's connection string you are connecting to `SQL Server Express`

Answer (score 0):

Well, its weird, after detaching and attaching the DB again, changed the connection string to this

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL 
Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\CineX.mdf;Integrated 
Security=True;Connect 
Timeout=30";
```

It worked.